# I can't loop trough a dictionnary in my Django Template

Tags: python, django, html-table, django-templates

I'm trying to loop trough a dictionnary to create a simple table with the keys in a column and the values in the other.

So in my view I create the dictionnary vegetables_dict. I loop trhough the "items" of a "cartitem". If the item doesn't alrady exists I created a key with the name of a ForignKey of "item" and a value with its attribute quantity. Otherwise I increment the already existing key with the corresponding quantity

```
def dashboard_view(request):

    carts = Cart.objects.filter(cart_user__isnull = False)
    cartitems = CartItem.objects.all()

    vegetables_dict = {}
    for item in cartitems:
        if item.stock_item.product_stockitem.name in vegetables_dict:
            vegetables_dict[item.stock_item.product_stockitem.name] += item.quantity
        else :
            vegetables_dict[item.stock_item.product_stockitem.name] = item.quantity

    context = {
        'carts' : carts,
        'cartitems' : cartitems,
        'items' : vegetables_dict
    }
    return render(request, "maraicher/dashboard.html", context)
```

In the template i Tried :

```
     <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"> Récapitulatif de récole</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <th>Produit</th>
                <th>Quantité</th>
                <div>{{items}}</div>

                {% for key, value in items.item %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{key}}</td>
                    <td>{{value}}</td>           
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
       </table>
```

{{items}} render the dictionnary but the table is empty.

Any idea what is happening?

I aslo tried

```
{% for item in items %}
   <tr>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
      <td>{{item.item}}</td>           
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: missing another "s"? `{% for key, value in items.items %}`

Comment: @JonSG It works if no dict key `items` is present: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: {% for key, value in items.items %} indeed worked! Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @JonSG In the django templating language, functions are called implicitly and parentheses are not allowed (unlike jinja2).

Comment: @user2390182 Thanks, I come from the jinja2 side of the templating house :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be in Django's template:

```
            {% for key, value in items.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>           
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @user2390182 a "s" was missing, the correct syntaxe is

> {% for key, value in items.items %}

Answer (score 0):

You must try this

```
{{items}}

{% for item in items %}
 <tr>
  <td>{{item}}</td>          
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can't use pythonic brackets inside templates. Also, `items()` returns `key` and `value`, it means it return a tuple.

Comment: It is still wrong.